# Turn drawing into a Mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I would like to ask if it is possible to make a drawing into a mesh. That would be very helpful. It can be a 2d plane formed like a cube or something.

Here is what I mean:
[image: Heres the Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Grease Pencil to Geo]

You can do this with a **Grease Pencil** sketch, it has a **Convert to Geometry Routine**.

[image: Grease Pencil to Geo, lots of Vertices upon Conversion]

However, the paths created with this **take ALL the curve points of the Grease Pencil sketch into the new mesh**, so this may not be a perfect solution.

[image: Grease Pencil to Geo from Polygon Drawing]
Update:
Actually, using the **Polygon Drawing Mode** this is pretty much exactly what you want. Closing off the endpoints is a bit fiddly, but otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: So i managed to make one, thanks. but now i would like to ask you if you can tell me how to make these 6 edges?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, from your earlier example, I would guess, you want to give the edges some extruded depth. As this is a different problem, you need to open another question for that, though.

Comment: Yeah, let me explain it better. I've made the exact same shape as your 3rd picture with Draw Poly in Object Mode. Now if im trying to convert it to polygon curve its saying an error message saying : "Current Grease Pencil strokes have no valid timing data, most timing options will be hidden!" :x

Comment: Alright mate, got it. Sry for my stupidity, it was behind the drawing all the time! Haha I love blender. (for real)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the closest you get to doing that is importing an svg file form a vectors graphis program (adove illustrator for instance). Then you'd turn that into a mesh. problem being that is very really messy and results into a ruined mesh with too many faces. 
Best option is to draw what you want to make, plug it in the background (hit "N" and look for the "background image" option", then use that as a reference.
The grease pencil you are using, at least in Blender 2.79 is mainly use to leave notes to yourself or other operator.